# adressing the right selector in Yii

Tags: php, jquery, html, yii

I'm having trouble getting the click event on a save button.

Let me explain.

I have a view index which displays a list of posts. 
For each post,  there is a button to add a comment.
When the user click on add a comment,  I renderPartial a form where I have a input field for the comment and 2 buttons, 1 to save and another to cancel.

If I look  the html through  firebug,  I can see

```
<input id="save" type="button" value="Save">
```

but if I right click on the html page and click on view page source, I cannot find the

```
<input id="save" type="button" value="Save">
```

that's why I suppose my jquery script doing things on button click

`$('#save').click(function(e)`   ....   does not work,  I put a alert in the code to see whether I go inside the function but no alert message is displayed.

I must add that the click event function for the button to add comment is in the same script and works (when I look at html source code, I can see the id of add comment)

Do you have any idea of what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the form is added after the original DOM load. You need to use the `.on` function and bind it to a DOM element that exists on original page load. So you could do this:

```
$('body').on('click','#save',function(e) {
    //more code here
});
```

Or you need to bind the `.click` to `#save` after you have rendered the form on the page. You can't bind an action to an element before it exists in the DOM.